# An optimized way to completely remove elements from a list that occur more than n times

Tags: java

Solution.java

```
public class Solution {
public static ArrayList<Integer> solution(int[] data, int n){
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if(n == 0){
        list.add(0);
        return list;
    }
    for (int x : data) {
        int sameTaskCount = 0;
        for (int y : data) {
            if (y == x)
                sameTaskCount++;
        }
        if (sameTaskCount <= n)
            list.add(x);
    }
    return list;
}
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int[] list = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5};
    int n = 1;
    ArrayList<Integer> newList = solution(list, n);
    System.out.println(newList);
}}
```

Solution.java (uses HashMap) **HASMAP DOES NOT PRESERVE ORDER HENCE SCRAPED**

```
public class Solution1 {
public static ArrayList<Integer> solution(int[] data, int n){
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> elementCountMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i : data) {
        if(elementCountMap.containsKey(i))
            elementCountMap.put(i, elementCountMap.get(i)+1);
        else
            elementCountMap.put(i, 1);
    }
    elementCountMap.entrySet().removeIf(entry ->(entry.getValue() > n));
    return new ArrayList<>(elementCountMap.keySet());
}
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int[] list = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5};
    int n = 1;
    ArrayList<Integer> newList = solution(list, n);
    System.out.println(newList);
}}
```

Is there another way to do this which requires lesser time for execution? The sample input I used here is just for testing purpose, the input can be up to 99 integers, and the input will not always be sorted. Both of these programs work well in IDE but they fail multiple test cases when I submit the code.
Here is the actual problem statement:

> Write a function called `solution(data, n)` that takes in a list of less than 100 integers and a number `n`, and returns that same list but with all of the numbers that occur more than `n` times removed entirely. The returned list should retain the same ordering as the original list. For instance, if data was [5, 10, 15, 10, 7] and n was 1, solution(data, n) would return the list [5, 15, 7] because 10 occurs twice, and thus was removed from the list entirely.
>
> Constraints: Java 8, limited execution time, no wildcard imports

Comment: Where is the code using hashmaps, and how are you benchmarking? The example you showed has only 9 elements, so performance is not going to be an issue, unless you need to do this for very many small arrays.

Comment: Just use a Set.

Comment: Is the initial array (`int[] list`) is guaranteed to be *sorted* as in the example?

Comment: This looks pretty much optimal, but more to the point, 99 integers is not enough for you to need to optimize anything.  It'll be fast even if you use a terrible algorithm.

Comment: 99 integers is not that much. First, make it work. If it is fast enough -> job done. Else you may need to optimize :)

Comment: @kaya3 I've edited and added the code for hashmaps. I use `nanoTime()` to calculate the execution time. This is just an example input, it can be up to 99 integers.

Comment: @Burkhard it does work in an IDE, but it fails when I submit the code. So I'm pretty sure it has something to do with optimization.

Comment: @LouisWasserman yeah, but it is failing the test cases provided, so I'm sure optimization is an issue.

Comment: Java Streams: `<T> List<T> solution(List<T> data, int n) { Map<T, Long> quantities = data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())); return data.stream().filter(el -> quantities.get(el) <= n).collect(Collectors.toList()); }`

Comment: You Can process the whole list in memory. Consider doing that to find those entries that are to be discarded and then create the list to return.

Comment: 99 elements is a very small number when it comes to the efficiency of this kind of algorithm; so you should make clear your question is asking about micro-optimisations, not an asymptotically efficient algorithm. By the way, your hashmap-based solution can be rewritten to use the [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) method to avoid looking up the same key twice with an `if` statement.

Comment: Also, if your code fails multiple test cases then it doesn't make sense to make it more efficient; it doesn't matter how fast you can give a wrong answer.

Comment: *"it is failing the test cases provided, so I'm sure optimization is an issue"* Wrong! --- 1) The `HashMap` solution is failing the test cases because you failed this part: *"The returned list should retain the **same ordering** as the original list"*. `HashMap` doesn't retain order. --- 2) It is also failing test cases, because you reduce the counts to 1. E.g. `solution([2,3,1,2,3,2], 2)` should return `[3,1,3]` (remove all 2's), but your `HashMap` solution returns `[1,3]`.

Comment: @Andreas Noted, I'll be scraping the hashmap method.

Comment: Why a list containing `[0]` is returned for `n == 0` regardless of the input data?

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to create a frequency map of the numbers in the array and then filter the numbers whose frequency is less than `n`. The `Stream` API makes it easier to do it in a clean and concise way.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static List<Integer> solution(int[] data, int n) {
        return Arrays.stream(data)
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity())).values()
                        .parallelStream()
                        .filter(list -> list.size() <= n)
                        .flatMap(List::stream)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5 };
        // Test
        int n = 2;
        System.out.println(solution(list, n));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5]
```

**Oracle's tutorials on `Stream` API:**

1. [Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams, Part 1](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html)
2. [Part 2: Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, your method appears to be slow.  It works great for large numbers.  But the limit is taking in 100 numbers into a list.  The `parallelStream` doesn't help probably due to setup time,etc, verses the smaller list size limitation.

Comment: @WJS - Thanks for your feedback. I haven't tried my hands at benchmarking yet . I will comment about the performance once I have benchmarking stats.

Answer (score 2):

As it has already been said, it would be better to calculate frequency map for the input array/list and filter out the elements exceeding the given threshold:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Solution {

    // solution for array
    public static List<Integer> solution(int[] arr, int n) {
        if (n < 1) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        Supplier<Stream<Integer>> streamSupplier = () -> Arrays.stream(arr).boxed();
        Map<Integer, Integer> freqMap = streamSupplier.get()
                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)));
    
        return streamSupplier.get().filter(x -> freqMap.get(x) <= n).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    // solution for ArrayList
    public static List<Integer> solution(ArrayList<Integer> list, int n) {
        if (n < 1) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        Map<Integer, Integer> freqMap = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)));

        list.removeIf(x -> freqMap.get(x) > n);

        return list;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be relatively fast to my previous attempts.  It is hybrid solution to short circuit the grouping process.  It uses a map but for internal use only so it preserves order of remaining elements and uses Java 1.8 or earlier releases.

- It simply groups the values together in lists using the list value as a key.  So each list contains all the values of that magnitude(i.e duplicates).
- once the list size of the current value exceeds the threshold, the elements in the map for that value are removed from the main list.
- the set is used to quash further processing of values that have been removed.
- After iteration of all the elements, the remaining list of values is returned.

```
public static List<Integer> solution(int[] data, int n) {
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i : data) {
        if (set.contains(i)) {
            continue; // already removed
        }
        list.add(i);
        map.computeIfAbsent(i, k->new ArrayList<>()).add(i);
        List<Integer> temp = map.get(i);
        if (temp.size() > n) {
            set.add(i);
            list.removeAll(temp);
        }
    }
    return list;
    
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random(23);
    int[] data = r.ints(20, 1, 6).toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    int n = 4;
    List<Integer> newList = solution(data,n);
    System.out.println(newList);
    
}
```